# Netty handler were blocked

Tags: netty

I developed a netty handler, which  is a sample class inherit SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler. I noticed that every 8- 10 minutes, all my work thread was blocked simultaneously, the pause time can be 500-1000 ms, each work thread paused same length of time.

I wonder which thread can stop all work thread?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds that the Garbage-Collector runs a full garbage collections and so "stops-the-world". Check your GC logs to verify